# Raspberry Pi Official 7” Monitors not working

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen, raspberry-pi-os

I am having trouble getting 2 Raspberry Pi Official 7” TouchScreens to work.
I have tried them each on 2 different Raspberry Pi 4s with multiple Ribbon Cables making sure they are in the correct orientation.
I have tried different SD Cards and multiple flashes of Raspberry Pi OS 64Bit with the File System Expanded and a full upgrade and sudo reboot done prior to using the touchscreens.
I have tried with USB and GPIO to power them.
I have used different power supplies.
I get the color boot screen then a flashing terminal and a blip of a raspberry pi splash screen and then it will either go white or a darker gray and won’t recognize any touch or show picture.
Both work fine with HDMI output to a monitor on the same images.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you insist on using a beta OS (which has many known deficiencies) expect problems. Use Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: i am using Raspberry Pi OS and i have seen multiple people using 64Bit with no problem including one i know personally.

Comment: The fact remains it is **Beta**, clearly labelled as such. Most of the basic stuff works, but it is incomplete.